# How can I use MATCH() with differently catagorized data?

Tags: excel, types, excel-formula, match

I have a spreadsheet `A` which contains a list of departments. One cell contains the department ID 76560 with the data type set to **Text**. (*Format Cells → Number → Text*)

Spreadsheet `B` contains detailed information about department 76560 I want to reference from spreadsheet `A`. However, spreadsheet `B` has the department ID's data type set to **General**.

I want to use [INDEX/MATCH](https://superuser.com/a/1228559/358766) to match up the department ID's, but unfortunately MATCH only seems to work the department ID is formatted as text in both documents.

**To summarize:**

- Spreadsheet `A` stores the ID number using the **Text** data type.
- Spreadsheet `B` stores the ID number using the **General** data type.
- `MATCH()` only works if the data types are identical.

**If two spreadsheets are storing the same ID using two different data types, is there a way I can still match up information between the two spreadsheets?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match Number to text:

```
=MATCH(TEXT(A1,"@"),SheetA!A:A,0)
```

The reverse:

```
=MATCH(VALUE(A1),SheetB!A:A,0)
```

Comment: Text to number is the second.  The format does not matter.  If the format is text and the value is `123A5` it will find a match in cells formatted as general that have the same value.  The issue is text or dates that are text when comparing to values that are not text.  Text to Text it does not matter the formatting.  Number to text does not work and one must be converted to the other.